# How to preview an image before and after upload?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am going to preview an image or photo in a form, but it doesn't work and the HTML code looks like this as below:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="personal_image" id="newHotnessForm">
    <p><label for="image">Upload Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="imageUpload"/></p>
    <p><button type="submit" class="button">Save</button></p>
        <div id="preview">
            <img width="160px" height="120px" src="profile pic.jpg" id="thumb" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

and incorporated JS code/script below:

```
<script type="text/jaavascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var thumb=$('#thumb');
    new AjaxUpload('imageUpload',{
    action:$('newHotnessForm').attr('action'),
    name:'image',
    onSubmit:function(file,extension){
        $('#preview').addClass('loading');
    },
    onComplete:function(file,response){
        thumb.load(function(){
            $('#preview').removeClass('loading');
            thumb.unbind();
        });
        thumb.attr('src',response);
    }
    });
});
```

There are 2 main questions on my form:
1. Why doesn't the preview of the image or picture work?

2. How to paste the photo from the form when the save button is clicked, it will go/link to another PHP or PHP page that I created?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preview an image before it is uploaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: This is the simple method https://stackoverflow.com/a/61380951/11766145

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try this: (For Preview)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Working Demo [here>](http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/1/edit)

Comment: Your solution is really work,but is it will work where the pic or image that I uploaded that link to another page under the code like `<form id="form1" runat="server" action='page.php'>`?

Comment: @meVeekay, can we set maximum number of image in your above solution ?

Comment: am using multiple input, how can it be done with above code

Answer (score 8):

meVeekay's answer was good and am just making it more improvised by doing 2 things.

1. Check whether browser supports HTML5 FileReader() or  not.
2. Allow only image file to be upload by checking its extension.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input id="fileUpload" type="file" />
    <br />
    <div id="image-holder"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("#fileUpload").on('change', function () {

    var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
    var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

    if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

            var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
            image_holder.empty();

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $("<img />", {
                    "src": e.target.result,
                        "class": "thumb-image"
                }).appendTo(image_holder);

            }
            image_holder.show();
            reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Pls select only images");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

On input ***type=file*** add an event ***onchange="preview()"***

For the function `preview()`  type:

`thumb.src=URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);`

Live example:

```js
function preview() {
   thumb.src=URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="file" onchange="preview()">
    <img id="thumb" src="" width="150px"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
                    #######################
                    ###  the img page   ###
                    #######################


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#f').live('change' ,function(){
            $('#fo').ajaxForm({target: '#d'}).submit();
        });
    });
</script>
<form id="fo" name="fo" action="nextimg.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="f" id="f" value="start upload" />
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="upload" />
</form>
<div id="d"></div>


                    #############################
                    ###    the nextimg page   ###
                    #############################


<?php
     $name=$_FILES['f']['name'];
     $tmp=$_FILES['f']['tmp_name'];
     $new=time().$name;
     $new="upload/".$new;
     move_uploaded_file($tmp,$new);
     if($_FILES['f']['error']==0)
     {
?>
     <h1>PREVIEW</h1><br /><img src="<?php echo $new;?>" width="100" height="100" />
<?php
     }
?>
```

Comment: This is not really work on nextimg page,the image didn't displayed and previewed.Is it involved any database?if not,of course, my project is trend to run at client-server.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#ImdID').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="ImdID" src="" alt="Image" />
```