# preview uploaded file (image)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file that already uploaded to the server using `input type="file"` (PHP), my question is, how can I preview the image before I download it. I think of to put a preview button at each of download file name link. Onclick on the preview button, it will popup and show the image.

Does anyone know the coding for preview image?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207575/how-to-preview-a-image-before-and-after-upload

Comment: @positlabs is it use the same coding to preview image after the image is uploaded?how can I retrieve the information from the server before display the image?

Comment: You mean like a thumbnail?

Comment: @bfavaretto not a thumbnail, but a new window/modal window to display the image..

Answer (score 0):

You can use some javascript/jQuery:

```
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files) {
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                if(input.files[i]) {
                    preview(input, i);  
                }
            }   
        }
    } 

function preview(input, i) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#divID').html('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" alt="Image currently not accessible" />');
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
}

    $('input[type=file]').on('change', function() {
        readURL(this);
    });
```

and for the HTML part:

```
<div id="divID"></div>
```

Note that this uses quite a bit of resources with large images.

Comment: hi, just wonder which part of your coding called the images path and file name?Is it `e.target.result` ?

Comment: Hello, Yes, e.target.result corresponds to the image source. We use the readURL function to get the right input file and also because this function is made to handle multiple files at once. Technically you could associate readURL and preview, what is important is the FileReader part.