# Get a user selected file as a base64 encoded string for a live preview of the image as well as for linking it in the final result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, base64

I am using a PHP file uploader to enable a user to upload images. However, due to some issues it is not working at all - the images are not uploading and the PHP script is not even creating an (empty in such cases) entries in a file.
As a workaround, I am trying to use base64 encoding. The user clicks the `input button` which executes a little JS function. It reads the said image via `readAsDataURL()` and then uses `onload` to change the `src` of the `img` tag to this result. The function:

```
function readIMGURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#theIMG').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
```

(Thanks to meVeekay here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207641/4112779)

This works well for displaying the preview of the image in the desired place. However, to complete the course of my application, the entire contents of the parent `div` is copied and placed in another location (or another `div`, another file, parent `div` processed by a script and placed in another `div`, etc)

The said div:

```
<div id="toCopy">
<img src="#" alt="" id="theIMG">
</div>
```

And the calling button:

```
<form style="  margin-top: 10%;" id="imageform" >        
   <input style=" margin-top: 10%;" class="input-btn" type="file" onChange="readIMGURL(this);">            
</form>
```

After "uploading" the image, it is posted via `XMLHttpRequest` to a working PHP script which does its job based on the above `toCopy`.

(I'm suspicious that the 
`$content = str_replace("\\", "", $content);` I added in the PHP script to remove extra escape sequences added during the `POST` may be messing up with the base64 text, but as far as I know, base64 doesn't have `\` anywhere.
Also, I have tried removing this instruction to no avail)

Eventually, in the final result, the image does not appear, instead a missing image image appears.

What could I be doing wrong, and what may be the possibilities to solve it?
Do I need to further modify the JS variable(s)/encode something else to enable it to be viewed as a proper base64 image?

All possibilities and proper explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: You're going to need to upload the code which reproduces this result - it's too difficult to ascertain exactly what behavior your script is exhibiting (and how to fix it) without actually seeing it.

Comment: @ᴊᴏɴᴀᴛʜᴀɴʙʀᴏᴏᴋs this is the only code of any consequence on the image selected. Adding the other parts which I feel maybe related, nevertheless.

Comment: That's not necessarily true - clearly the code you've provided isn't the point of failure here. It would be good to have some context.

Comment: @ᴊᴏɴᴀᴛʜᴀɴʙʀᴏᴏᴋs I have added the code, can you please ponder over it?