# Display Image form a file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to display an image via an input field and then display it. How do I make it work.
In principle, I would simply like to display a picture that serves as a profile picture, which is later saved in a database. But first it should be easy to upload so that it is displayed

```
function Speichern() {
    var Profilbild = document.getElementById('pb').value;
    var c = Profilbild + ".png"
    document.getElementById('Profilbild').src = c;
}
```

```
 <div id="Profil">
     <img id="Profilbild" src="./Bilder/Profil.png" height="100px" alt="">
 </div>
 <form action=""onsubmit="Speichern();return false">
     <label for="username">Nutzername:</label>
     <input id="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="<?php
         echo $_SESSION['username']; 
     >">
     <label for="email">Email:</label>
     <input id="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="<?php
         echo $_SESSION["email"];
     >">
     <label for="pw">Passwort:</label>
     <input id="pw" id="pw" type="password" placeholder="<?php
         echo $_SESSION["pw"];
     >">
     <label for="pb">Profilbild:</label>
     <input type="file" id="pb" name="pb" accept="image/*">
     <button type="submit" >Ändern/Speichern</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preview an image before and after upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207575/how-to-preview-an-image-before-and-after-upload)

Comment: Nope :( i tryed this Code but it doesnt Work

Comment: Just for clarity, “first it should be easy to upload so that it is displayed”, when you say “upload” do you mean “transmit to server” or are you intending for no server and just previewing on the client side?

Comment: It does work, there is a live demo included in the linked post.

Comment: @ChrisHaas  Oh yes my mistake  sorry

Comment: @TimAnthony i try it and on the Demo Link ist doesnt Work too

Comment: @TheBrain04 are you sure you have javascript enabled?!

Answer (score 1):

The code of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207575/how-to-preview-an-image-before-and-after-upload) Thread works.

But it seems like the [live demo](https://jsbin.com/uboqu3/1/edit?html,js,output) has some mistakes. If you look in the console you will see the following errors

```
runner-4.1.8.min.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsbin.com/uboqu3/1/edit?html,js,output' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure stylesheet
'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

(anonymous) @ runner-4.1.8.min.js:1
runner-4.1.8.min.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsbin.com/uboqu3/1/edit?html,js,output' was loaded over HTTPS,
but requested an insecure script
'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

you can fix this by replacing

```html
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jquery-ui and jquery-ui.css aren't necessary for the code to work so you can just remove this script and the link tags.

The full working code would like that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jsbin automatically includes the script. So you have to include it yourself -->
<script src="yourscript.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</body>
</html>
```

yourscript.js

```js
     function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(150)
                        .height(200);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
```